# Can't check the value of an EditText in an AlertDialog.Builder

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to check the value of the EditText inside my AlertDialog.Builder so that I can prevent the user from entering nothing in the EditText.

For some reason when I use the code below it never gets into the `if (mEditText.getText() == null || test == "")` statement, it always executes the else statement instead.

Any ideas?  Thanks folks.

```
    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

        LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        final View textEntryView = factory.inflate(R.layout.file_save_dialog, null);
        mEditText = (EditText) textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.file_name_edit);
        final Animation shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.shake); 

        return new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext)
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_save)
            .setTitle(R.string.file_name_title)
            .setView(textEntryView)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    String test = mEditText.getText().toString();

                    //This if never works...it always hits the else statement
                    if (mEditText.getText() == null || test == "") {
                        mEditText.startAnimation(shake);
                    }
                    else {
                        finish();
                    }

                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.dialog_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    finish();
                }
            })
            .create();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it in the Android way:

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mEditText.getText()) {
    mEditText.startAnimation(shake);
} else {
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

put it like this

```
if (test == null || test.length() <= 0) {
    mEditText.startAnimation(shake);
}
else {
    finish();
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Checking the length did work, but I'm puzzled as to why my original code did not work.

Comment: Your original code didn't work because in Java Strings are compared with equals(), not ==

Answer (score 1):

If you want compare two String values, use method `equals()`.

For example:

```
stringOne.equals(stringTwo);
```